Incredibuild and Visual Studio 2022, stays endless in "Preparing build tasks"
On the same machine:
Incredibuild and VS 2019 works as expected.
But when using it with VS 2022 every build stays endless in "Preparing build tasks".
Interestingly we have one machine which does not have this problem.
We checked network environment, software configurations, agent and coordinator settings,
we don't see any differences or reasons for that behavior.
We have had already contacted Incredibuilds support some time age but they couldn't help either.
Has anyone seen such an issue before ?

Maybe you can check the logs. Incredibuild logs are typically located in C:\ProgramData\Xoreax\Incredibuild\Logs. Look for any anomalies or differences between the machine that works and those that don't.

As a workaround I made a shortcut to the Incredibuild Batch Build Dialog. If I click on the Build Button the build process starts as expected

It's important to note that this only works when VS 2019 is installed and the project uses the VS 2019 toolchain

With the help of the Incredibuild Support Team we found out that Symantec Endpoint Protection kills the Build Runs.

This could sometimes happen if the Incredibuild version is not ready to support the specific VS version you use.
If you can add more information on this, it would be better in order to suggest an actual solution.
I can add the Incredibuild released 10.16.1 on August 26, 2024 in order to support Visual Studio 17.11
If you can try with it or with the 10.17 version released afterwards it could help.
